# How slow is mongodb's skip() in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

I've seen a lot of questions regarding this and all answers seem to imply `.skip()` method is expensive & I should use ranges. What I'm trying to ask is when does it get slower? I have a database of 11000 records, will it be slow to do pagination with a limit of 25.

Also is there an alternative or a better way of doing pagination in mongoose. Is **mongoose-paginate** module fast? how does it work (skip or something else)?

Thanks :)

Comment: Best to just try it and see how it performs with your own data. mongoose-paginate uses skip and limit.

Comment: @JohnnyHK :( I thought they might have updated mongodb/mongoose in 2018. Skip is costly in my case. :(